# BSOD while in VS 2013 source file corrupt

Tags: c#, .net

I ran my MVC project from VS 2013 and it caused a BSOD on my Win 7 box. Now when I go back into the project that 1 source file is all messed up. It's basically all NULL values when I open it with notepadd++. When I double click from vs it opens it in notepad and not VS. I made changes I haven't checked in yet. Is there anywhere else this may have been saved?

Comment: I assume you don't have any kind of continuous backup which saves past versions (like Carbonite or something), and viewing the file's properties in Explorer doesn't show any Previous Versions?

Comment: It smells like a file system error. Maybe it's a bad sector, maybe it's a bad hard disk, or maybe just a 1 in a billion chance that some calculations went wrong.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I once lost some important source code in a similar manner, but I was able to get it back using [Redgate's .Net reflector](http://www.red-gate.com/products/dotnet-development/reflector/) on a previously built assembly in the \Debug folder. Maybe that could be a last resort?

Comment: How did you do that? I downloaded the trial version but don't see how you look at the dll to get the source.

Comment: Figured it out. This is saving me big time thank you so much!!